# User field to entity reference

Tags: 8, users

I have created a content type, with a custom field.

Then i have created an Entity Rereference on the users fields, so the user can select from those nodes on their user account settings.

The idea is to allow the user select values from a content type, this is working, but i need to show this field with the selected values on a custom module with php.

I got already the user object but not able to get the nodes selected from the entity:

$id is the current user id, this is ok!

```
$user = User::load($uid);
```

Trying to getting the values:

```
$selectedBrands = [];
foreach ($user->field_brands as $item) {
  if ($item->entity) {
    $selectedBrands[$item->entity->id()] = $item->entity->label();
  }
}
```

Im just getting this:

```
Array()
```

But the user has 2 selected brands here.

Comment: Your code is correct, the issue is either `$uid` is not what you think it is, or the `field_brands` is the incorrect field machine name. You could try to further debug this with [Devel](https://www.drupal.org/project/devel) Kint `kint($user);` and inspect the user object.

Comment: Thank you, im doing a reference to nodes, that has some images i need to show, is this possible to load the node id and show the image? The node selected by the user, anyway im still getting array()

Comment: As No Sssweat said, your code is correct. Did you try the debugging he suggested? It would seem either your user is not loaded correctly (incorrect $uid) or you have the field name incorrect. Both as No Sssweat indicated.

Comment: yes its working now!, using kint i was able to get the variable, thanks!

Comment: Just a quick question, how do i print the values on a twig? I have already an array of values, so i assume, a foreach, but how?, im passing the variable to the theme:
'#imagenLogo' => $imagenLogo,
The imagenLogo variable is an array of values